# Why would apache/passenger not serve updated content to the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Using a React/Rails 6 app with Apache/Passenger on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
I've made updates to some of the JSX and confirmed changes display on my development server.
Updated the source code on the production server and restart the apache service.
However the browser shows no changes to the web pages.
Does Apache or Passenger serve a cached version of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the issue, needed to run 'RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile'